# Problem with Realm List<> and ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, realm, objectmapper

I have an old project I'm trying to port from Swift 3 to Swift 4 to Swift 5.  It looks like I need to eventually move off of ObjectMapper, but before I can do that, I need to fix this error to get the code to compile again. Unfortunately, this is just one of many instances of this issue across my entire codebase, so it's not something I can avoid.

The code `let sortedWorkoutDiary = List(from: exercise.workoutDiary.sorted(byKeyPath: "date"))` generates the `Argument type 'Results<Workout>' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'` error:

```
    func recordWorkout(_ newWorkout: Workout) {
        let lastWorkout = exercise.workoutDiary.last // grab the last workout for later comparison

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            exercise.workoutDiary.append(newWorkout) // write the workout no matter what
        }

        if let secondToLastWorkout = lastWorkout { // only bother checking out of order if there is a last workout...
            if newWorkout.date < secondToLastWorkout.date { // ...and now look to see if they are out of order
                let sortedWorkoutDiary = List(from: exercise.workoutDiary.sorted(byKeyPath: "date")) // ERROR: Argument type 'Results<Workout>' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'
                try! realm.write {
                    exercise.workoutDiary.removeAll()
                    exercise.workoutDiary.append(objectsIn: sortedWorkoutDiary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to add Realm List<> support to ObjectMapper

```
class ListTransform<T:RealmSwift.Object> : TransformType where T:Mappable {

    typealias Object = List<T>
    typealias JSON = [[String:Any]]

    let mapper = Mapper<T>()

    func transformFromJSON(_ value: Any?) -> List<T>? {
        let result = List<T>()
        if let tempArr = value as? [Any] {
            for entry in tempArr {
                let mapper = Mapper<T>()
                let model : T = mapper.map(JSONObject: entry)!
                result.append(model)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    func transformToJSON(_ value: Object?) -> JSON? {
        var results = [[String:Any]]()
        if let value = value {
            for obj in value {
                let json = mapper.toJSON(obj)
                results.append(json)
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}
```

Simplified view of the object:

```
final class Exercise: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var notes: String?
    var workoutDiary = List<Workout>()
    dynamic var goal = 0

}

extension Exercise {

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        notes <- map["notes"]
        workoutDiary <- (map["workoutDiary"], ListTransform<Workout>())
        bodyWeightMultiplier <- map["bodyWeightMultiplier"]
        sortOrder <- map["sortOrder"]
        username <- map["username"]
    }

}

final class Workout: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    var sets = List<WorkSet>()

}

extension Workout {

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        date <- (map["date"], DateTransform())
        sets <- (map["sets"], ListTransform<WorkSet>())
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, the answer is the Workout object is not of type Decodable. You would typically do `class Workout: Decodable`. But that error indicates you are trying to decode a Results object which contains the Workout Object? Is that intentional? You didn't indicate which line caused the error so can you clarify?

Comment: The error was inline in the code: `let sortedWorkoutDiary = List(from: exercise.workoutDiary.sorted(byKeyPath: "date"))` I've adjusted to make it easier to see.

Comment: That's not the proper use of List - that's defined as *List<_> (from: Decoder) throws - creates a new instance by decoding the given decoder* so whatever is passed has to conform to the decodable protocol. However, It's not clear why you are doing that in the first place; the code takes a Results object, sorts it by date, assigns it to a list and then that List is put back into the original Results object for saving. The order of the objects doesn't appear to matter since you sort by date anyway. There doesn't seem to be a reason to do that - why not just sort the Results and call it done?